# How to declare local variables inside an object and reference directly in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function as:

```
function Main(){
    var self = this;
    self.reserve=false;
    self.change = function(){
        self.reserve=!self.reserve
    }
    self.service={
        to_add: 0, to_delete: 0,
        init: function(data){
            self.service.to_add = data[0];
            self.service.to_delete = data[1];
        },
        custom_func: function(data){
            self.service.init(data);
            self.service.change;
        },
        /*there are many other functions here*/
    }
}
```

Now as you can see inside the `service` object I need to reference everything like `self.service.xxx`.

But is there a better approach where I could reference the objects local variables directly like `to_add=data[0]` instead of `self.service.add_to=data[0]`, but to use variables from other objects can follow the default way `self.object.xxxx`.

Reason: To reduce the script size. There are many such variables and functions inside the `service` object.

**Note:** *Please change the question accordingly. I was not able to come up with any.*

Comment: inside `self.service.init()` you can reference the `service` object using `this`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah! Thanks. got confused!